# Google Invisible reCaptcha not stopping SPAM submits

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha, invisible

I have implemented Google reCaptcha on a site, for the newsletter subscription form, and it does not stop spam. I got up to 20 spam subscribers per day!
What am I not doing correct? Please have a look at the code:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="databasepage.php" id="formid" >
<div id="g-recaptcha-answer"></div>
<input name="email" placeholder="Email..." type="email" required>
<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_key" data-callback='onReturnCallback'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
var onReturnCallback = function(response) {
document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-answer').innerHTML = ''; 
var url='proxy.php?url=' + 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';  
$.ajax({ 'url' : url, 
dataType: 'json',
data: { response: response },
success: function( data ) {
var res = data.success.toString();
if (res ==  'true') { 
document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-answer').innerHTML = 'Please wait for a redirect.';
document.getElementById("formid").submit();
} 
else {
document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-answer').innerHTML = 'Verification incorrect.';
grecaptcha.reset();
}
} 
}); 
}; 
</script>
```

**proxy.php**

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('You are not allowed to access this file.');     
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
$url=$_GET['url'];
$response=$_GET['response'];
$secret = "secret_key"; 
$params = array('secret'=> $secret, 'response'=> $response);
$json=file_get_contents( $url . '?secret=' . $secret . '&response=' . $response);
echo $json; 

?>
```

I have tested this with Incognito Mode, I get the step when I have to verify pictures, if I am not logged in Gmail etc., in reCaptcha admin area I have no errors, but I STILL RECEIVE SPAM EMAILS IN MY DATABASE!!!

What is wrong in my approach?

Comment: You haven't done any server-side validation. Javascript doesn't stop bots from submitting your form. Maybe use Google's library: https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Comment: Doesn't the proxy.php code which is called from the <script></script> do this job of server-side validation? Why an additional library is needed, should't the server verification be made at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify with the parameters received?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what your PHP code was doing. I assumed that was the code that processed and handled the form input. What sort of server-side validation are you doing in databasepage.php to make sure the recaptcha response is valid?

Comment: database.php is a page generated from the email marketing application, where the email address is stored. That page can be a thank you page for double-opt-in confirmation of email, or an error page if the email address is already subscribed. I have no server side validation on that pages.

Comment: You need to validate the recaptcha response in the page that performs the action you are trying to protect. There is nothing that is preventing the bots from simply submitting the form to databasepage.php, and since that page doesn't perform any validation, that's why you're getting so many spam submits. It is not necessary to use a library, but if you use one it will save you from reinventing the wheel, and you know the code was written by Google, so it's unlikely to contain errors and if it does, just update the library when a patch is released.

Comment: I have no control to edit the php pages generated by the email application. There is no other solution?

Comment: You can't protect a warehouse with an unlocked door by asking visitors to check in with security guards. Burglars will just skip the check-in.

Comment: If you can't control the generated PHP pages then you need to tunnel everything through something you **do** have control over.